# How to manage different task which need to be called by AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a external library to use which communicates with a server via the internet. Everytime I need to get some info from the internet, android forces me to use an asynctask. So far no problem. However, I'm getting more and more tasks to retrieve (in different ways) data from the internet and I'm not liking the increase of different classes for each single call. 
So long story short: I have different internet-calls, and instead of creating an asynctask-class for each call, I would prefere one single class to manage all different calls. Is that somehow possible? And more importantly, what is the proper way to do so?

Comment: Android doesn't force you to use AsyncTasks - there are many ways to call web services. Maybe something like Retrofit would help: https://github.com/square/retrofit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also facing similer problem like you have.But i solved this problem by Reflection Technique. I have made a method to prevent increasing of different classes to call single hit.
I have made single asynctask class and passed functionName and context of the activity and returned response by onPostExecute.

Here is sample -

AsyncTaskConnection.java

```
public class AsyncTaskConnection extends AsyncTask<String, String, Object>{
    JSONObject mainObject;
    Context mContext;
    String returnFunctionName;

    public AsyncTaskConnection (Context context){
         mContext = context;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // preExecute
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... arguments) {
        String apiFunctionName = arguments[0]; // get api FunctionName 
        String jsonString = arguments[1]; // get data
        returnFunctionName = apiFunctionName+"Response"; // return function name
        // some connection code...


        //then call...
            try {
                ht.call(NAMESPACE, requestEnvelop);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.d(mContext.getClass().getName(), "Io exception bufferedIOStream closed" + ex);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mainObject.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            return "no";
        }
    }

    // main thing is there, i have use the reflaction here....

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object backresult) {
        Method m;
        try {

            m = mContext.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(returnFunctionName, String.class);
            m.invoke(mContext, (String) backresult);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

> in caller class

```
//call this class where you want and get dynamic response 
new AsyncTaskConnection(this).execute("getHomepage",jo.toString());

// and make response fuction

protected void getHomepageResponse(String backresult) {
            try {
// this is your response
                mainObject = new JSONObject(backresult);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And there can be many ways to get result that you want.

Comment: That is ok, if you have like one single call. My network tasks are slightly more complex. However, I will try to make something like this. The issue is, I have like 20 lines of code that all rely on the response of the network-connection, then I can't wait in the main thread for the response. You know what I mean?

Comment: What do you exactly want @RobertStettler i didn't get it. Can you please explain more

Comment: "I have like 20 lines of code that all rely on the response of the network-connection", @RobertStettler can you give more explaination for these line on the code level Then maybe, i will getting your problem clearly..

Comment: I think I know how to handle it. Each call which is more than 1 line of code I can simply add as a method to the `AsynTaskConnection` class and call that method with your solution. I just need to group then togheter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but you need to create some generic AsyncTask that takes API(url to call) and handler when result is received.

Async class:

```
public class AsyncTaskThread extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {
    //instance variables
    Handler myHandler;
    public AsyncTaskThread(String uriString, Handler myHandler) {
       //set these arguments to respective instance variables 
       this.myHandler=myHandler;
    }
      protected Object doInBackground(Object... obj){
          //business  logic
      }
    //----implement other  methods of Async as per your requirement
      @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
          super.onPostExecute(result);
          Message message = new Message();
          message.obj = result;
          myHandler.sendMessage(message);
}
```

}

Pass handler for thread:
You need to pass handler to above Async task in argument.

```
new AsyncTaskThread(uri,new MyHandler())

import android.os.Handler;
private class MyHandler extends Handler{
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Model response = (Model) msg.obj;
        }
}
```

when result received call sendMessage() method on passed handler from your async task.

My suggestion:
If you are using okhttp client library for API calls, please see https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes

Comment: Thanks, I don't get what does in //-- implement methods stand? I think you can have only one doinbackground, not?

Comment: I have edited post , I mean it is for implement other method of Async class

Comment: That was not my question: afaik you  can have only one "doinbackground" method per class....

Comment: Yes , I forgot to write it. A subclass which extends Async at least override doInBackground()